# How to speed up import of .sql dump file in to AWS RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, rds

I'm trying to import a 55 meg .sql file in to an AWS RDS instance.  The dump file was generated with this command:

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword dbname > dbname.sql
```

I'm running the import with this command:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword --host=x.rds.amazonaws.com dbname < dbname.sql
```

The import was running for about 20 minutes, so I decided to abort thinking something was hanging.  It aborted on a line which is 20% of the through, so it seems the import was working, but set to take about an hour and 40 minutes to import 55 megs of SQL.

Is this normal?  If not, how can I do it right?

Comment: It can be normal if the indexes are terrible.

Comment: Do you have option to generate the dump again? In a first time, according to information provided by you, I suggest using the option [`extended-insert`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_extended-insert) when generating the dump.

Comment: It's a wordpress DB.  It takes about 4 minutes to import it on localhost to localhost.  Can the extra 1 hour and 36 minutes really be network lag?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out doing the dump according to this made the import take about 2 minutes: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.SmallExisting.html